# Problem in passing data from one async function to another

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-upload, async-await, callback

I am trying to load a picture in json and pass that json to another asynchronous function. But I am confused and cannot figure out how the value can be passed to the `create(json)` function. I would be grateful for any help.

```js
async function send() {
    let form = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
    let json = await construct_json(form, data => {
    return data;
  });
    await create(json); //The problem is I cannot pass json to this function
}

function getBase64(file, callback) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    callback(e.target.result);
  };
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    return e.target.result;
  };
  return reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

async function construct_json(form, callback) {
  let data = await getBase64(form.get("picture"), data => {
    let json = {
      picture: data
    };
    callback(json);
  });
}
```

Comment: `json` is `undefined` since `construct_json` doesn't return anything

Comment: also `reader.readAsDataURL` doesn't return a Promise ... so your `getBase64` is also wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX do you have any suggestions what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: firstly load the image and when image is loaded then pass it in another async task.

Comment: you need to learn not tu use both callback and promise (async/await) syntax with the same function ... you do it in function send and construct_json ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either callbacks or promises ... trying to use both is code smell

```
async function send() {
    let form = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
    let json = await construct_json(form);
    await create(json); //The problem is I cannot pass json to this function
}

function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            resolve(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

async function construct_json(form) {
    let picture = await getBase64(form.get("picture"));
    return {picture};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! You can improve this answer by removing callbacks in function arguments.

Comment: @Helen - yeah, I forgot to change that :p